# Can't delete disabled software fonts under Other Software, after upgrade to Saucy (13.10)

Tags: ppa, 13.10

I just upgraded from Raring to Saucy. *Software & Updates >> Other Software* shows disabled entries, saying `Disabled after upgrade to saucy`. I can't check or uncheck these disabled entries to delete them. How can I remove them?

Answer (score -1):

You must have permisson or you cannot do it right now. More detail, you must enter password when required.

Comment: This is really too vague to be considered an answer, I'm afraid.